# Laravel 5.2 CSRF Token expires too quickly

Tags: laravel-5, token, csrf

I am working on Laravel 5.2 application and I am facing this issue for all my views.

The CSRF token is getting expired too quickly. In fact, I am just occupying the time to fill up the form and as soon as I submit it,I get `TokenMismatchException` exception.

I tried to search for the problem on Google, found git for some similar issues and even tried on Laracast for similar problem without any success.

My .env file has some lines like this:

```
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

And this is my post method for login:

```
public function postLogin(CookieJar $cookieJar, Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request, [
           'email1' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|string'
        ]);
        if($user = User::whereEmail($request->email1)->first() ) {
            if(Hash::check($request['password'], $user->getAttributes()['password'])) {

                if(!$user->getAttributes()['is_active']) {
                    return redirect('/login')->withErrors('Your Account is not Activated Yet!');
                } else if($user->getAttributes()['is_deleted']) {
                    return redirect('/login')->withErrors('Your Account is Banned!');
                } else {
                    # Success
                    $cookie = Cookie::make('user_id', $user->getAttributes()['id'], 864000);
                    return redirect('/')->with('message', 'You have Successfully Logged In!')->withCookie($cookie);
                }
            } else {
                return redirect('/login')->withErrors('Your Login Information is Wrong!');
            }
        } else {
            return redirect('/login')->withErrors('Your Login Information is Wrong!');
        }
    }
```

Please help me.

Added .env file content and postLogin method.

Comment: Any reason why you're not using the Laravel `Auth` functionality to handle your login validation, etc?

Comment: Login code is someone else's code.

Comment: One hack I found is when I removed SESSION_DRIVER=file line from .env file it works fine.

Comment: that's not a hack. Laravel simply reverts back to the default session driver.

Comment: Yeah I mean is that something related to this?

Comment: I have the same issue, every refresh a token expries

Answer (score 0):

You could have a problem with sessions not being saved in your environment. Perhaps do php artisan cache:clear or manually clean and reset priveleges in storage/framework/sessions/ if sessions are saved to file.

I'm assuming you already add the token to your form properly with csrf_token() or something that provides it.

Comment: Yes I have added csrf_token() to my every POST method forms.

Comment: I have updated the content of the question please check if this can help you track the problem better.

Comment: The permissions on the storage path could be an issue to. Make sure your web service has full write and read privileges in all folders in storage/