# How to debug 419 error on LoginPage in Laravel? (Not using AJAX)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

Each time I try to login into my Laravel app I get 419 error, thou I have `@csrf` inside my form tag.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}" class="form-auth-small m-t-20">
    @csrf
    //rest of code...
</form>
```

I read thru all topics on StackOverflow, but mostly I saw `cache: clear` and `key: generate` suggestions, which are not helping me. Also, I've cleaned my browser hundreds of times.

Once again it happens on the standart login page and `master.blade.php` has `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`.

Here is what I see in my dev console
[image]

**UPDATE 2:**
I noticed that a new session file is generated on each request because my cookies are always empty.[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ajax LARAVEL 419 POST error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46472812/ajax-laravel-419-post-error)

Comment: @aynber Read carefully the description. I don't send any ajax request

Comment: You made no indication of that at the time my comment was made. One thing you can do is open up your developer console and watch the request when you submit for your form (make sure preserve log is checked), then check the request payload to see if the csrf_token/_token is listed.

Comment: I found something. There is token in `Request Headers` and no token in `Response Headers`. What does it mean?

Comment: With laravel 419, it's almost always the CSRF for me. Add `@csrf` to the form tag. I don't know what the meta tag does, but `@csrf` is still required on my laravel sites.

Comment: @TinCan I have it right on the next line after opened form tag.

Comment: The token should only be in the request headers. That's what you send to the server, the Response Headers is what the server sends back to you.

Comment: @aynber do you know what should I check to debug this? If so can you write all possible aspects as an answer? _I am trying to save one week of work_

Comment: Since it's not over Ajax, the only thing I can really think of is session life or timestamp mismatches, where the browser token does not match the token stored in the session. You can possibly verify this by doing some logging inside of the VerifyCSRFToken class, and check to make sure your sessions are not being lost. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43107711/laravel-5-2-csrf-token-expires-too-quickly might help a bit

Comment: You can check the conditions of method `"handle"` in class `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken` one by one. At the end of the method you see that a TokenMismatchException is thrown in case the conditions above do not apply. This will lead to a 419 HTTP-status code in further processing. So probably you will get some insights what is causing your problems by checking the handle function in detail.

Comment: @aynber  Each time I update login page redis generates a new session file. I guess this is it. Have any idea how to figure out why?

Comment: Check the session life in PHP, and try tweaking it in `config/session.php`. System time can also throw it off if it's way off.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

:(
It was whitespace before `<?` in one of config file

Comment: kind of wish this was an answer to the title of the question, and not a one liner explaining what the specific problem was this time....

Comment: @VirtualDevice And how did you found out?

Comment: @feeela just went thru all my commits and check what changes I did

Answer (score -1):

I was getting larvel login 419 error only when i was double clicking login button. this is due to csrf token changing on login attempt and fixed by disabling login button after first click.